# GraalVM native-image fundamental linker error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, linker, graalvm-native-image

I'm trying to create a simple native image of hello world, using graalVM v20.0.0 CE.

Initially I was getting a "native toolchain" error, but having launched a command line from "x86 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS2017", I'm over that hurdle.

The problem now is a string of linker errors:

> java.lib(jni_util.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_fprintf referenced in function JNU_PrintString
>
> java.lib(jni_util.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp___iob_func referenced in function JNU_PrintString
>
> net.lib(net_util_md.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_sprintf referenced in function NET_ThrowNew
>
> net.lib(net_util_md.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_printf referenced in function dumpAddr
>
> jvm.lib(JvmFuncs.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_vfprintf referenced in function jio_vfprintf
>
> jvm.lib(JvmFuncs.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_vsnprintf referenced in function jio_vsnprintf
>
> MSVCRT.lib(vsnprintf.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_vsnprintf
>
> MSVCRT.lib(vsnprintf.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__vsnprintf
>
> D:\Tools\graalvm-ce-java8-20.0.0\bin\helloworld.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals

These all seem directly related to that most basic of function calls, `printf`.

I reviewed `native-image`'s command line options, and hoped explicitly setting `--shared` or `--static` would do the trick, but no dice.  None of the other native-image command line options looked relevant.

I further tried starting from the VS2015 version of the same command prompt.  Nope.

So I'm stuck.  Is this something I can fix outside of getting graalvm's source and taking a crack at it?

Comment: I just discovered how to list all the `-H` options: "native-image -H:PrintFlags=".  There are pages and pages of options to work through.  Promising.

Comment: I'm seeing similar error reports (same missing functions) with people converting from VS2013 to VS2015.  Is `native-image` and co built with VS2013?

Comment: Poking around in the guts of several of the .exe files in graal/bin, all of them rely on MSVCR100.dll, which was released with visual studio 2010.  As I'm using the 2017 and 2015 environments, it seems likely that I'm screwed.

Comment: I've been using the Java 8 build.  I'm hoping the Java 11 build will use a more modern back end.

Answer (score 1):

I switched from GraalVM's Java 8 build to their Java 11 build, `gu install native-image`, and now my `helloworld` converted to a native image just fine when done from the aforementioned VS2017 command prompt.